# Listener on edit of a document with Google Sheets API v4

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am running a script locally with Node.Js using the "Google Sheets API v4" to read and record data in a Google Sheets. I would like to know if it is possible to create a listener with the same API that it is triggered when someone edit a document?

Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

To create a listener without many API calls you need the [drive push api](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push), or you can [check for changes](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-changes).

The google sheets API does not support this feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use triggers via App Scripts, onEdit() is called after every edit.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers